# Is it possible to use HYB or ELL sparse matrix multiplication(SPMV) in CUSPARSE 11?

Tags: cuda, cusparse

I am updating my CUDA code with sparse matrix multiplication(SPMV). I found the HYB or ELL format sparse matrix related functions in cuSparse 11 are removed. But for my practical problem, HYB format SPMV runs better than CSR format. Is there any method to reuse HYB format in cuSparse 11? Like including some other library? Or I must write these kernel code myself?

I know this is not a specific code issue. But I really need some advice.

Comment: Those legacy formats were deprecated during the CUDA 10 release cycle, and removed in CUDA 11. There is no replacement I am aware of. If this is a genuine  performance regression, then maybe raise a bug report on the CUDA developer portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use HYB or ELL sparse matrix multiplication(SPMV) in CUSPARSE 11?

No it is not possible.  Those formats were deprecated in CUDA 10.x and are no longer supported.

Reformat your matrix storage to use a supported format.  If you believe there is a [performance issue](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/is-it-poosible-to-use-hyb-or-ell-sparse-matrix-multiplication-spmv-in-cuda-11/181832/2), [file a bug](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-report-a-bug/67911) with a demonstrator.